# AppsScript urlFetchApp call with headers

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

This works in postman, but not in apps script. Any suggestions? The only thing I can assume is how I've specified the header but I'm using the same key/value as in postman.

```
function callAPI() {

var options = {
     headers : {
       'AccessToken' : 'ThPbxJ3XeA83hkdPVCGiJ10XJ'
     }
   };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.company.com/Call?TargetEndPoint=SEARCH&query=www.airbnb.com', options);
console.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `but not in apps script`? And, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: I can't provide the official documentation because it's an API internal to my workplace. I've anonymised the parameter for AccessToken and the URL/endpoint. What I can say though is that in postman all I need to do to get this to run is put "https://api.company.com/?TargetEndPoint=SEARCH&query=www.airbnb.com" in the request URL field and "AccessToken" and "ThPbxJ3XeA83hkdPVCGiJ10XJ" as one additional header on the headers tab. Everything else has been left as default.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood about `I can't provide the official documentation because it's an API internal to my workplace.`. From your replying, I couldn't understand `but not in apps script`. If an error occurs, can you show it? And, although I'm not sure about the actual endpoint, in your URL, `/?` of `https://api.company.com/?TargetEndPoint=SEARCH&query=www.airbnb.com` is used. When you modify `/?` to `?` like `https://api.company.com?TargetEndPoint=SEARCH&query=www.airbnb.com`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: And, in your query parameter, the specific characters which are required to do the URL encode are includes? Also I'm worry about it.

Comment: I don't believe it's a syntax in how I've formed the request URL as I'm literally copy/pasting from postman to apps script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comments were not useful for your situation.

Comment: What I can tell you is that this example is based more or less on this API call. My company just puts a simple wrapper API around it -- https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/5190535/TzCV1iRc#69b925b6-23c6-456a-9b4b-3aaa2a811fa5

Answer (score 0):

I've realised now it's because the API is in a UAT environment and google.com cannot see into that namespace "eg. stg.company.com"